# Paid with, by or in human lives

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

I'm currently writing a formal letter in which I'm complaining about the dangers of the process of tanning leather in Bangladesh.

> But the ugly truth is that this price difference is actually being paid in Bangladesh; *in/ with/ by* human lives.

Which preposition should I use here?

Comment: Normally **in** to refer to the mode of payment, or currency, that which is tendered in payment.  It's being paid for in gold... in Canadian Dollars... in Euros.... in human lives...  Why price *difference*? https://www.google.com/search?q=%22paid%20for%20in%20human%20lives%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I presume the cost of production is lower in Bangladesh than elsewhere, with the difference compensated by the "cost" in human lives.

Answer (score 2):

> But the ugly truth is that this price difference is actually being paid *by* Bangladesh **in** human lives.

Since the "human lives" are people in Bangladesh, you can say that the cost is borne by the people in general. So, "*by* Bangladesh".

And as @Tᴚoɯɐuo commented, *in* is usually used for tendering payment.